# Steganographically hide encrypted packets for VPN, Tor, etc?

Tags: cryptography, vpn, tor, steganography

We all know about different encryption methods used today in secured connections like VPN, Tor, etc.
However, there is an issue with usage of those. Even if the outsider can not decrypt the message, or establish the exact addresses if it is in onion routing, there is still a possibility to determine, that some IP address is participating in the secret connection, and then it is trivial to discover the physical person behind the IP address.

So is there any method to hide **the usage of encrypted connection** steganographically, means, the observing outsider will no "even" notice, that a secure connection is established. For example, this connections will pretend to be unsecured http traffic, or unsecured file exchange.

Comment: No, because someone needs to know where the packet goes.

Comment: did you understood the question? I m asking how to mimic encrypted packets to be not encrypted. Of course there will be some route to end IP-adress

Comment: Yes, I understood it. No, it's not possible in a way that remains undetectable.

Comment: OP, you might want to consider using TOR with TOR Bridges to hide the fact that you are using TOR from someone censoring or monitoring your networking activity. See tb-manual.torproject.org/bridges and support.torproject.org/censorship/censorship-7 for more info.

Answer (score 3):

There are several standards used to mask traffic as another protocol, this will however not protect you against the observer recognizing that your mere connection with a certain remote host is a bad connection.

One example of such an implementation is [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html), which masks arbritrary TCP traffic as HTTPS traffic. However, if this traffic is actually looked at closely by the observer, they will quickly recognize that it's Shadowsocks. It's meant to bypass automated filtering, not manual inspection.